# for looping syntax error, unexpected '[' PHP 5.6

Tags: php

pls help me for my this code
i'm using PHP 5.6 and i can't upgrade for some reason

please help me for fix this code

```
public function __construct($data)
    {
        $key = array_keys((array)$data);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++) {
            $keyPriv = $key[$i];
            $this->$keyPriv = ((array)$data)[$key[$i]]; // THIS IS THE ERROR CODE
        }
    }
```

I get this error when execute
**PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['**

Comment: There is no syntax error in that code for any currently supported version of PHP. You might want to consider upgrading. Otherwise, add `$data = (array)$data;` to the beginning of your function and just use `$data` elsewhere. However I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: thank you @Nick, i already add $data = (array)$data; in the beginning and change my code to $this->$keyPriv =  $data[$key[$i]]; and it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.6, you need to cast your `$data` parameter to be an array before accessing it like that, you can achieve this by simply doing this within your constructor function before calling it later on.

```php
public function __construct($data)
{
    $data = (array) $data; // Cast the variable data as an array.
    $key = array_keys($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++) {
        $keyPriv = $key[$i];
        $this->$keyPriv = $data[$key[$i]]; // Access to $data now works.
    }
}
```